# Linkedin API Pulse Share

Tags: linkedin-api, pulse

I am trying to integrate my blog to Linkedin Pulse by connecting to my linkedin app. I found that posting to API `/v1/people/~/shares` shares my update but I can't figure out how to post it on Pulse - long post.

Is it even possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Posting on Pulse is not available using LinkedIn's public API. And as far as I know, they are not offering this to their partners either.

Comment: Liad is correct that this is not currently possible via API.

Comment: So the only way to automate this process would be curl?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it with Curl. The tool is logging in to your linked in (user and password). Gathers the token and post to LinkedIn pulse, additional request is used to upload image and tags using post ID at that time.

Cheers!