# Linkedin 999 Request denied

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, linkedin-api

I don't know if somebody has been able to solve this. In a AWS server, we are running our application. We extract the content of articles published in web pages. It is ok for nearly everything, but Linkedin pulse articles returned 999 Request Denied.

I know that Linkedin has blacklisted AWS ip's, and also I am specifying which User Agent to use.

But there is a way to avoid that or any end point api to query for pulse articles?

This is my code so far

```
var httpWebRquest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/time-c-suite-social-network-damian-corbet?trk=prof-post"));
httpWebRquest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36";
var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRquest.GetResponse();
...
```

and GetResponse throws

> The remote server returned an error: (999) Request denied

Comment: Referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592163/linkedin-api-pulse-share), LinkedIn doesn't seem to provide pulse access through their API. So I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

LinkedIn does not provide any API endpoints for accessing Pulse articles.  Further, you should be aware that scraping that information is also expressly prohibited under Section 8 of their terms of service:  https://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement

Comment: Cool! Thanks so much for the answer. We will add a message saying that we can't get that info from Linkedin.

I just wanted to confirm that I wasn't able to do it ...